# How to get raster layer metadata in python for QGIS 3.6?

Tags: python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I am loading imagery as raster layer through a URL. I need to store its metadata as JSON string in db for future reference.

I tried getting the metadata via `layer.metadata()` and then tried to get `json.dump()` for that object but an empty string was returned.

When I use the `layer.htmlMetadata()` function I do get all the information but I need all the details as JSON.

Comment: I need to form a JSON containing all the data displayed while viewing Layer Properties in Information Tab.